# SQL: How to clean this data and dynamically convert them into columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, trino

In my database, I have a column (progress_history) which captures values such as this:

```
eg1: {'2022-11-01': 44038.91099579527, '2022-12-05': 44038.91099579527, '2023-01-21': 20623.839917193636, '2023-02-01': 20623.839917193636, '2023-02-25': 20623.839917193636}
eg2: {'2023-05-26T12:53:50.708195+00:00': 0.0, '2023-05-26T12:53:51.034034+00:00': 0}
```

This captures value of a metric at different time periods

What I am trying to achieve is, for last 6 months from today, the code should look at different months and capture value associated with that month.

For example, in eg1, for Nov'22 it should give 44038.91, etc & in eg2, for May'23 it should give 50.71 (lowest date value for month).

Tried following code, which is giving me values only when the metric is captured in 1st day of the month. Also, I am unable to get the months dynamically. Using Trino DB.

```
with kpis as (
    select
        k.kpi,
        k.progress_history,
        replace(k.progress_history, '''', '"') as progress_cleaned
    from
        kpis as k
)
select
    kpi,
    json_extract(
        progress_cleaned,
        '$."2022-10-01"',
        '$."2022-11-01"',
        '$."2022-12-01"',
        '$.error()'
    )
    emits(
        "2022-10-01" double,
        "2022-11-01" double,
        "2022-12-01" double,
        error_column varchar(2000000)
    )
from kpis
;
```

Comment: As per [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path)  you are mentioning only 1st date of month as identifier for **json_extract()**  which is why you are only getting 1st date values.

Comment: do you need month wise the least date values if there are multiple dates of same month?

Comment: Usually you should have a key and a value in JSON. In this case it looks like your keys are already a value and on top of that you have a second value. Where does this model come from?

Comment: @lsrat Why reference documentation for MySql when the question is clearly marked for Postgers?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to convert the string for `progress_history` column. Your CTE correctly does this (although IMHO you should do this when storing the data so to always have valid JSON in the database). The remaining is just transformation of extracting the key-value pairs from the JSON into standard columns and the date (timestamp) manipulation of the *key*. I do not know where you got the syntax user for *json_extract ... emits* (perhaps the invalid reference to MySQl documentation), but it was not form Postgres; neither exists. To extract the key-value pairs use the function [jsonb_each()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html). To get just the lowest value for each month use the window function [row_number()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) in conjunction with the [date_trunc()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) function. Taken all together to arrive at: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Nd5S4Ypd))

```
with kpis_hist(kpi, progress_history) as
     ( select k.kpi
            , replace(k.progress_history, '''', '"')::jsonb   
        from kpis k
     ) --select * from kpis_hist
select kpi "KPI"
     , to_char( date_trunc('month', key), 'Mon''YY')  "Month" 
     , round(value, 2)  "Value" 
  from (select k.kpi
             , js.key::timestamptz  
             , js.value::numeric 
             , row_number() over (partition by k.kpi, date_trunc('month', js.key::timestamptz)
                                      order by js.key) rn
          from kpis_hist k
             , jsonb_each(k.progress_history) js
        ) sq 
 where rn = 1       
 order by kpi;
```

NOTE: A data changes for the demo. For exp2 changed the expected value to 123.46 because the expected value 50.71 is not the value of the key-value pair, it is part of the key (timestamp).